# ¿Cómo enviar correos en Django en una fecha y hora determinadas?

Tags: django

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de gestión de actividades y estamos usando Django 1.11 para desarrollar dicho sistema.

Cada vez que se inserta una actividad se activa un signal en el sistema y se notifica al creador mediante un correo. Ya tengo puesta la configuración del correo en mi `settings.py` y ya probé que el signal funcione. Hasta ahí todo bien.

Sin embargo, ahora las actividades tienen valores opcionales que le permiten al usuario configurar una "alarma". El usuario especifica en qué fecha y hora quiere ser notificado sobre la actividad que insertó, así como qué mensaje va a recibir.

Mi problema es que no sé qué utilizar para mandar los correos en la fecha que desea el usuario y no al instante como se hacía antes. He revisado varios posts en español e inglés pero no encuentro una respuesta clara, aunque mencionan a Celery como una posible solución.

¿Qué puedo utilizar para mandar los correos en la fecha y hora que desea el usuario? Gracias de antemano.